# What is mind contain of?

Tags: vipassana

What are the contain of the mind?Are emotions being mind contain or they are from of mind energy?how does mind differ from each other?how  person being act differently.?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the standard answer of what the mind is according to Buddhism. 4 aggregates.

1. Feelings. (Pleasant, unpleasant, neither pleasant nor unpleasant.)
2. Perception. (Spontaneous recognition)
3. Volitional formations.
4. Consciousness. (6 consciousnesses, 5 physical sense base consciousness and 1 mind consciousness.)

We all have the same structure of the mind. The difference from person to person is merely that different feelings at different time for different people, (only 3 possibilities)

We can possibly speak different languages, so our perception of sounds is different, I perceive Russian language sound as noise, those who knows the language perceives their meaning spontaneously.

We choose to react differently to different things, but we all have the same basic template to choose from. Metta, or anger, or generosity, or greed. Emotions fall under the category of volitional formations.

We can be conscious of different things at different times. Like he's sleeping, I am awake etc.

The mind object can be anything, including the 4 aggregates of the mind itself, it's perceived via the mind base, and when mind consciousness arise to come together, we have contact of mind object. When contact happens, feelings arises and is dependent on what contact it is, what perception we have of the contact etc.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more esoteric response would be as follows:

“The Mind” that we think we have doesn’t exist.

The true mind, or Buddha Mind, is one that is shared between all sentient beings and is pure, clear, true and excludes nothing. It does not require zazen to be still, it does not lack enlightenment. It is this mind that we experience in deep samadhi.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an interesting video about: [His Holiness the Dalai Lama talks on the "Nature of the Mind"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gO7RQi55asY)

I find it a very interesting point of view, also because is very similar to the most advanced knowledge that we have in neurosciences.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is the combination of Thoughts and Mental factors that creates the mind, however, the brain and consciousness also a requirement for the sense sphere to function which finally gives rise to experience the awareness of the five aggregates of existence.